# Checkbox did not check/uncheck while [checked] property update

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I need to make a toggle button. I need to prevent toggle button default behavior (i.e. on click check/uncheck). So I apply **preventDefault** on checkbox click event. Now I update checkbox **[checked]** propery. but nothing heppend.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" (change)="toggleChange()">
```

**TS**

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  onClick($event) {
    this.callback.emit();
    $event.preventDefault();
  }

  @Input() isChecked;
  @Output() callback = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // check isChecked value
    console.log(changes);
  }

  toggleChange() {
    this.callback.emit();
  }
```

Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyp9jz

Comment: why do you add this "strange" `@HostListener('click', ['$event'])`? It's not necesary (implements ngOnChanges is unnecesary too), see your forked stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kxs677?file=src/app/toggle-button/toggle-button.component.ts

Comment: @Eliseo I want to prevent default behavior or checkbox. I need to apply checkbox check/uncheck basis of server response.

Answer (score 1):

```
export class AppComponent  {
  isChecked: boolean = false;
  name = 'Angular';

  toggleCallback() {
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
  }
}
```

Use type boolean and initialize the value

```
export class ToggleButtonComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() isChecked: boolean;
  @Output() callback = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // check isChecked value
    console.log(this.isChecked);
  }

  toggleChange() {
    this.callback.emit();
  }

}
```

Also remove the Hostlistener, you do not need it, cause you call *toggleChange()* on the change event.

Comment: how to prevent default behavior of checkbox if remove HostListener

Answer (score 0):

**instead of swapping value**

> use this

```
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" (change)="toggleChange($event)">
```

code

```
toggleChange(event): void {
      console.log(event.checked)
  }
```